# ubuntu uninstallation issue

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu since one year but now I stuck with some problem that sudo command not working ,even my internet is also disabled,USB device is not detecting the system is automatically shutting down just frustrated with all this Please help me out .

Comment: Yeah I think there is no option but I m having my data on it and the problem is its not detecting any devices except keyboard and mouse so how I install windows even my internet connection is disabled

Comment: I am having only Ubuntu 14.04 ,I guess I made some mistake in using chown command and change the root permission that makes a big effect so plz help me out guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you could have got to the state you describe, never the less it seems that the most sensible way to recover would be to boot from the Ubuntu installation CD in "try ubuntu" live CD mode, and use that to transfer your data to a USB pendrive or similar, so that you can then simply install a fresh copy of Windows and then recover your files from the pendrive.

Comment: Sir the thing is I was changing permission of www file it all started there and I was trying installing other os but not CDROM is detecting not USB device is detecting and not internet is enabled all this thing is disabled just frustrated

Comment: karel, he's saying that nothing is working within his existing Ubuntu installation, correct me if I'm wrong there... This would not affect a different OS booted from a live CD which would then be able to read the files and back them up to removeable media.

Comment: That's right but how live CD can detect when CDROM is not working

Comment: mahesh kadam, without knowing what bad permissions you have set it's hard to advise how to undo the problem (it may not even be possible), so booting a separate OS from the installation CD would allow you to back up your files and then re-install either Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: Thanx Karel I think u got my problem right

Comment: mahesh kadam, if your system is not recognising the CDROM/USB during the boot process, eg BIOS/UEFI then this is not an Ubuntu issue, you need to change the boot order in the BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: I get u James sir but the I can put up error which is showing hope that will help u to solve my problem

Comment: The error I am getting is as follows:/usr/bin/Sudo must be own by uid 0 and have setuid bit set

Comment: OK, but this is an error when booted from your hard disk, not from a live CD....

Comment: Nope this error I am getting in terminal in Ubuntu while performing sudo

Comment: You cannot recover the permissions in this scenario without booting from a live CD and restoring the permissions from there, because you need sudo to change the permissions (of sudo) back.  As I said, it may be easier to boot from a live CD and back up your data files and re-install, depending on how much of your OS has had the ownership/permissions damaged.

Comment: Yeah I get u what u are saying but what if my CD drive is not detecting ,also I tried the bios setting its showing the DVD enabled there but I guess the problem is because of corrupt Ubuntu crash everything is corrupted internet,hardware but I don't know why keyboard and mouse perfectly working I m just confused

Comment: If your CD drive is not detected in the BIOS/UEFI, such that you cannot boot from it, then this is something that happens /before/ any OS is loaded, so your changing file permissions in the OS loaded onto the hard drive cannot be the cause... do you understand that I am telling you to boot a different OS from the one on your hard drive?

Comment: So what according to you that will work for me? Should I try for live CD by changing the boot priority but I dnt think it will work as my CD drive is not showing in drive menu in Ubuntu itself

Comment: Give me strength!...  Your CD drive is not showing up in Ubuntu booted from your hard drive because you have screwed up the permissions of a load of system binaries and probably device files...  therefore, if you boot from the CD, into a completely different OS to the broken one installed on your hard drive, then you will then be able to use sudo, and/or USB drives to either repair, or more likely back up files from the OS on your hard drive before wiping it and re-installing either Windows or Ubuntu...